# Difficulty working out which statistical test to perform

Tags: anova, predictor, time-varying-covariate

I am writing a research paper looking at how reported PTSD scores vary in those who have lost a loved one to homicide. I am investigating whether there is a difference in the scores at different stages of involvement with the criminal justice system. So I have one variable created which pin points the stage that they were out at the time that their PTSD score was gathered, e.g. investigation stage, during trial, after verdict, case closed with no verdict. My other variable is just the PTSD score. I want to use time as a co variate but I don't know which statistical test to use. I should mention that all participants are only in one group. The total data set is over 1100 participants. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have multiple measurements of the same individuals i.e. at different stages?

Comment: This will depend on a) How your PTSD score works and b) Whether you have data on the same people over time or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for a generalized linear (mixed) model / multilevel (hierarchical) model. Basically, you are regressing your PTSD scores on your time variable, which is a fixed effect, and you are testing how the PTSD scores change over time, if they change. The individuals are the random effects. I don't know what software you are using, but in R this is simple to do.